# how to update an open excel using POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to update an excel which is already open on my system using Apache POI and also through vba code running on some other excel?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache POI library [does not support](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) reading, writing, or executing macros in an Excel document.

Apache stores an internal representation of the worksheet in its memory model. You will have data concurrency issues if you try to have two different applications writing to the same Excel file.