# How to access/edit an already opened excel using Apache POI (in Java)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am automating a webpage using selenium (Java). There is a scenario where on a click of a button an excel sheet gets opened up.
I want to edit that opened excel sheet using Apache POI(Java).

I tried to search and got 2 hits but 1st solution is using C# and 2nd did not have any solution.

[1. Solution using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686886/how-to-access-an-already-opened-excel-file-in-c)

[2. No Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717331/how-to-update-an-open-excel-using-poi)

Comment: As far as I know, POI does not interoperate with any excel-viewers - it "just" provides methods for reading/writing files in the relevant formats.

Comment: It's not possible to [edit files locked by Office with POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524341). How about adding a test handler to your page, which is activated via some request parameter or test user-id, so the excel file is not opened but downloaded and you do the modifications on the unlocked file?

Comment: What you seems to want is COM automation using ActiveX `Excel` components. This is what [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) is for for example.